# Unable to parse JSON in javascript coming from remote server

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON returned from a remote server:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "questions": [{
        "id": 23,
        "text": "Is Sky Blue?",
        "response_type": "Multiple Choice",
        "created_at": "2014-12-05T06:37:20.947Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-04T00:00:56.915Z",
        "campaign_id": 38,
        "no_repeats": true,
        "max_repeat": 0,
        "yes_no": false,
        "type": "axy",
        "priority": 0
    }, {
        "id": 24,
        "text": "What is your current employment status?",
        "response_type": "Multiple Choice",
        "created_at": "2014-12-05T06:38:56.076Z",
        "updated_at": "2015-03-04T00:00:56.903Z",
        "campaign_id": 38,
        "no_repeats": true,
        "max_repeat": 0,
        "yes_no": false,
        "type": "axy",
        "priority": 0
    }]
}
```

I am using this code to fetch data from remote URL:

```
$.get( url, function( data ){
    alert(data.success); // Works
    alert(data. questions); // Returns Blank
});
```

`data.questions` returns empty. I tried to `eval` but it just returns `[object]`

What's wrong am I doing?

Comment: There is no dataType "json" in your code. Did you skipped it in example? It should not work even for succes if you don't have it in your code

Comment: @SeriousDron Interesting. I did not put `json` but it does return `success` as `true`

Comment: May be you should add it and see what happend. Also you could use console.log instead of alert to get more info. Starting with console.log(data) to see if data is actially what you expecting

Answer (score 3):

`questions` is an array. Try

```
alert(data.questions[0].id)
```

and you should get 23. If you do, that'll give you the insight you need into access the rest of the data.

Comment: Already tried that. Didn't work, I already had tried it and it returned `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

Comment: If that is true, then there's something you're missing that you've not shared with us that's causing the problem. As it stands, your JSON is fine and you should be able to access the data object as described - demoed here: http://repl.it/dHa ... is there any more code involved in this process? Can we access the endpoint that's returning the JSON?